# NextJS - component conditional render occurs problem with duplicated html ID's

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use NextJS in my current project. One of component has support component to render single row:

```
const SingleRow = ({ id, label, children }) => {

 return (
  <p id={id}>
   <span>{label}</span>
   <span>{children}</span>
  </p>
 )
}
```

and next in the same file:

```
...

return (
 <>
  <SingleRow
   id="firstRow"
   label="sample"
  >
   row1
  </SingleRow>

  {hasPhone && <SingleRow
   id="secondRow"
   label="sample"
  >
   row2
  </SingleRow>}

  <SingleRow
   id="thirdRow"
   label="sample"
  >
   row3
  </SingleRow>
 </>
)
```

hasPhone - value from a prop, just a string.

**Problem:**
When the second *SingleRow* has condition hasPhone - it has not correct HTML ID (in chrome dev tools & cypress does not see this ID) (should be secondRow, is: thirdRow). When I delete the condition, everything works ok, HTML ID's are correct.

Why this condition has an impact on HTML ID?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code above, I can only assume, since hasPhone is a string, it is beeing passed as an empty string so the second row will not be rendered, only the first and third.

```
const SingleRow = ({ id, label, children }) => {
  return (
    <p id={id}>
      <span>{label}</span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </p>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const hasPhone = "asas"; //make the string empty to omit second row

  return (
    <>
      <SingleRow id="firstRow" label="sample">
        row1
      </SingleRow>

      {hasPhone && (
        <SingleRow id="secondRow" label="sample">
          row2
        </SingleRow>
      )}

      <SingleRow id="thirdRow" label="sample">
        row3
      </SingleRow>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you see my updated question? About your answer - I know that empty string will hide my component :) The problem is with duplicated HTML ids after render.